# Memory Leak in "executeFetchRequest" Core Data (ARC)

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, memory-leaks

Here is a code where I get an array of objects:

```
-(BOOL)isAvailable:(NSString*)aName
{
    BOOL isAvailable = NO;
       
    NSEntityDescription *ed = [Queue entityInManagedObjectContext:moc];
       
    NSFetchRequest *fr = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fr setEntity:ed];
    NSPredicate *pr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"textName == %@", aName];
    [fr setPredicate:pr];
   
    NSArray *arr = [moc executeFetchRequest:fr error:nil];
       
    if ([arr count] > 0) {
        isAvailable = YES;
    }
       
    return isAvailable;
}
```

Memory leak is in:

```
NSArray *arr = [moc executeFetchRequest:fr error:nil];
```

There is no any leak if comment this line. I use ARC project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the line the leaked memory is allocated on and not necessarily the cause of the leak.

Without knowing what is leaked or how much memory, it is impossible to say much more.